# Loop Transpose a range of data in two columns into multiple rows

Tags: transpose

I am trying to tranpose range of data as shown below in 2 columns (colC and colD) to multiple rows. I used the below code but the problem in this code is, it transpose all data into single row. I need to the data in multiple rows.

Note: there is an empty row between each set of data in colC and colD.

```
My data is as below       I need the transpose rows as below starting from ColF

ColC    ColD              F    G    H    I   J    K   L    M    N    O
1       Q1                1    Q1   A   C1A  B   C1B  C   C1C   D   C1D
A       C1A               2    Q2   A   C2A  B   C2B  C   C2C   D   C2D
B       C1B
C       C1C
D       C1D

2       Q2
A       C2A
B       C2B
C       C2C
D       C2D
```

I tried the below code and it transpose correctly as expected, but it transposed the second row along with first row continuously with 2 cell gap putting all in single row.

I am facing problem in line 14. Also if possible i dont want to select the range, rather whole column C and D can be selected. I appreciate if anyone can help me with this code. Thanks

```
Code as below:
Sub TransposeMultipleColumnsSingleRow()
Dim SrcRange As Range
Dim TrgtRange As Range

xTitleId = "Transpose Multiple Columns into Single Row"
Set SrcRange = Application.Selection
Set SrcRange = Application.InputBox("Please Select the Range You Want to Transpose", xTitleId, 
SrcRange.Address, Type:=8)
Set TrgtRange = Application.InputBox("Please Select the First Cell of the Target Range(one cell only)", xTitleId, Type:=8)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

iRows = SrcRange.Rows.Count
iColumns = SrcRange.Columns.Count
For i = 1 To iRows
SrcRange.Rows(i).Copy TrgtRange
Set TrgtRange = TrgtRange.Offset(0, iColumns + 0)

Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```